# How to install specific version of cmake on mac?

Tags: macos, cmake, homebrew

I try to install an old version of cmake. I install .dmg file from [here](https://cmake.org/files/v3.5/).

But I couldn't use on terminal via `cmake xxx`. I know that I install for command line using `brew install cmake`. But it installs the latest version. How can I install a specific version?

Comment: What do you mean by "I couldn’t use"? Please be specific.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Homebrew install specific version of formula?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987683/homebrew-install-specific-version-of-formula)